# creating very basic react app manually without npx create

Tags: reactjs

I have create reactsample.jsx file then with the help of .babelrc converted to js file then use this js in an index.html file. However, since reactsample.jsx file has import from react so I also tried to do npm install react, react-dom... Even tried pointing script file from CDN but got forbidden 403 error. Now getting this error. index.html:1  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

If basic cannot work, then what's the point of using tools without having proper understanding.

I am trying to load react in html and be able to run it successfully in the browser. I do not want to use npx create